# .disabled not working for me when trying to disable a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have looked everywhere and everyone says to use `objectname.disabled = true` but in my project it doesn't work. Even when asking ChatGTP it says "Huh... should work lol". Please help me out here!

My Code: (I do have a css file however it should not affect `.disabled` not working so I will not add it here. I will after the fact if deemed necessary though.)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var atom_amount = 0;
    var matter_btn = document.getElementById('matter_btn');
    var matter_amount = 0;
    var matter_cost = 10;

    document.getElementById('atoms_btn').onclick = function() {
        atom_amount++
        document.getElementById('atoms_txt').innerHTML = "Atoms: " + atom_amount
        if (atom_amount < matter_cost) {
            matter_btn.disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            matter_btn.disabled = false;
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('matter_btn').onclick = function() {
        atom_amount = atom_amount - matter_cost
        document.getElementById('atoms_txt').innerHTML = "Atoms: " + atom_amount
        matter_amount++
        matter_cost = matter_cost + (2 * matter_amount)
        document.getElementById('matter_txt').innerHTML = "Matter: " + matter_amount
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>From Scratch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Style.css">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <game_name class="game_title">From Scratch</game_name>
        <shape class="resource_area"></shape>
        <resources_info class="text resources_text">Resources:</resources_info>
        <shape class="divider"></shape>
        <atoms id="atoms_txt" class="text atoms_amount">Atoms: 0</atoms>
        <atoms_button id="atoms_btn" class="button atoms_button">Create Atoms</atoms_button>
        <matter id="matter_txt" class="text matter_amount">Matter: 0</matter>
        <matter_button id="matter_btn" class="button matter_button">Create Matter</matter_button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have created a test file and tried `.disabled` and lo and behold it worked! However as soon as I went back to my main file it did again not work so I am extremely confused.

All I want is for my button to be disabled when certain conditions are met and to be reenabled when those conditions are not met.

Comment: What is the `matter_button` element? That's not a standard HTML element type, and it's not a valid [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) (their tag names [must have a `-` in them](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name)). How is it implemented? Does it extend the `HTMLButtonElement` interface?

Comment: I'm not gonna lie I thought that would just be me naming the variable or smth as the code executes just fine. Like I said I'm super new to HTML and since it worked I never bothered to check up on it.

Comment: While HTML allows any elements to exist, get event listeners, and have text placed inside of them, only valid elements are given semantic meaning and features (such as a button's ability to be disabled). Whatever `matter_button` is, it's not a valid HTML tag. You're probably wanting to use `<button>`.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button. They also have an excellent list of [all the tags you can use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you've made up your own HTML tag, `matter_button` (and some others). Since it's not a standard element tag, it just has a generic interface ([`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)), which doesn't provide the `disabled` reflected property that [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) ([`HTMLButtonElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLButtonElement)) and [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) ([`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)) have. If you used `button` (probably with `type="button"`, redundant as that sounds) or `input`, `disabled` would work.

Here's your code using `button`, with some other modernizations and suggestions inline (feel free to ignore them if you like):

```html
<!-- Updated to use standard element tags -->
<h1 class="game_title">From Scratch</h1>
<div class="resource_area"></div>
<div class="text resources_text">Resources:</div>
<hr>
<div id="atoms_txt" class="text atoms_amount">Atoms: 0</div>
<button type="button" id="atoms_btn" class="button atoms_button">Create Atoms</button>
<matter id="matter_txt" class="text matter_amount">Matter: 0</matter>
<button type="button" id="matter_btn" class="button matter_button">Create Matter</button>
<script type="module">
// No need for `DOMContentLoaded` if you use `type="module"` on the
// `script` element, which I recommend.
// See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules
// If you don't want to use modules, you could just put the `script`
// tag at the end of the `body`, just before the `</body>`
// end tag

// Prefer the new(ish) `let` and `const` over the old `var`
let atom_amount = 0;
const matter_btn = document.getElementById("matter_btn");
let matter_amount = 0;
let matter_cost = 10;

// Avoid assigning to old-style `onXyz` properties; instead, hook
// up event handlers with `addEventListener` as you had with
// `DOMContentLoaded`
document.getElementById("atoms_btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    atom_amount++;
    // I haven't changed it, but you might put the count in its own `span`
    // so you didn't have to repeat the `Atoms: ` prefix.
    document.getElementById("atoms_txt").innerHTML = "Atoms: " + atom_amount;
    // You can directly assign the result of the comparison, which is a boolean,
    // to the `disabled` property
    matter_btn.disabled = atom_amount < matter_cost;
});

document.getElementById("matter_btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    // You can use `-=` and `+=` to subtract/add and assign back to the
    // variable
    atom_amount -= matter_cost;
    document.getElementById("atoms_txt").innerHTML = "Atoms: " + atom_amount;
    matter_amount++;
    matter_cost = matter_cost + 2 * matter_amount;
    document.getElementById("matter_txt").innerHTML =
        "Matter: " + matter_amount;
});
</script>
```

That's just to get you started. I think there are probably still some logic errors in there (I wasn't sure what the logic should be).

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for the clarification. Since I've only ever programmed in Python and C# I thought that I was just declaring variables or smth. I has no clue I had to name them specific things.

Comment: Omg literally just changing it to a button type="button" made it work like a charm. Thank you so very much!

Comment: @TristanLovasz - Glad that helped. :-) I've updated the answer with a runnable example with some other suggestions (take or leave as you wish). Think of element tag names as *types* rather than *names* (names would be `id` or `name` attributes, depending on what kind of name you want [because yes, we have more than one in HTML]). Happy coding!